# Track student from our website to completion of registration on another site

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

Using `Google Analytics` we are wanting to track users and then know when they have completed our student registration form, as a goal.

The student registration is from another provider on a different website, but I know there has to be a way to tie these users together for goal conversion.

Would this work the same way as goals for ads? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you own and control the other registration form? I.e., can you add Analytics tracking code to it?

Comment: Yes, we could add tracking code to it with the help of the other provider.

Comment: In this case, this seems to be achievable with cross-domain tracking, where you share the client Id among several sites, to keep tracking the same visitor.

Comment: And would we still be able to create a goal when the user finishes the registration form?

Comment: Yes. Cross-domain tracking will send hits from multiple sites to a single Analytics property. You will be able to set up a goal based on the form's success URL, or an event generated by the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the following method:

**you need to have Google analytics installed on your target website**

1. Hyperlink from your website using the utm_source, utm_medium and campaign links
2. Create a goal in Google analytics where filling the form will redirect user to a thank you page or create a value that is filled in analytics on the target site.